# Access elements in Pandas Dataframe and sum up - elegant solution

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, grouping

I have a pandas dataframe with dates as index and several criterions (customer group, quantity, ...). Dates can occur multiple times as there can be different sells every day. An example could be:

date       --- quantity --- group

2018-03-22 --- 1 ---       100

2018-03-24 --- 10 ---      102

2018-03-25 --- 5 ---       102

2018-03-25 --- 2 ---       100

2018-03-25 --- 3 ---       102

What would be an elegant solution to sum up all elements with a specific date (index) that are in one group. So I'd like to have a dataframe that has only the unique dates as indices and columns that are the group numbers and the elements are the sum over the different quantities, so e.g. for 2018-03-25 it is 8 for group 102 and 2 for group 100.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks, Franz.

Comment: I think need `df = df.groupby(['date','group'])['quantity'].sum().reset_index()`

Comment: Thanks a lot. That answers my question perfectly. How would you then create a dataframe which columns are the different groups, index is dates and entries are the calculated sums?

Comment: If solution from comment above not working, use `df = df.reset_index().groupby(['date','group'])['quantity'].sum().reset_index()`

Comment: Thanks again for your quick answer. Your solution from above is working. I was wondering how to get a dataframe looking like:

date --- group100 --- group102
\n
2018-03-24 --- 0 --- 10
\n
2018-03-25 ---2 --- 8

Comment: I think need pivot - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe

Comment: Thanks again for you help.